# Splitting a string into different variables issues

Tags: javascript

I am trying to split the 2nd and 3rd part of a string.

Here is the string content:

```
var message = 'save ['content1', 'content2'] filename';
```

To separate this I am using:

```
const myarr = message.split(" ")[1];

const filename = message.split(" ")[2];
```

For `myarr` I'm getting just `['content`

and for the filename I'm getting the actual whole array.

What I'm I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex to split the string in two parts:

```
var message = "save ['content1', 'content2'] filename";
var matches = message.match(/(\[[^\[\]]+?\])\s*(.+)$/);
const myarr = matches[1];
const filename = matches[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

Do with regex `/(\[(.*?)\])/g`

https://regex101.com/r/i2Rhni/2/

**Updated**

For file name use `split` instead of match.And use `trim()` remove unwanted empty space

```js
var message = "save ['content1', 'content2'] filename";
str =message.split(/(\[(.*?)\])/g).map(a=> a.trim());
console.log(str[1])

//parse string to array using eval
console.log(eval(str[1]))
console.log(str.pop())
```

Comment: What about the filename?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the space inside the array between the elements

```js
var message = 'save ["content1","content2"] filename';

const myarr = message.split(" ")[1];

const filename = message.split(" ")[2];
console.log(myarr)
console.log(filename)
```

Comment: Please mind the `space` between `"content1",` and `"content2"`